# how to search in list of checkboxses in the same page using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-selectors

i have list of checkboxes options ,, the problem is that this list my contain more than 500 checkboxes , so i want make simple serch box to search of the list only in the same time and fetch the checkbox which user will search about it using the search box , i want do this trick using jquery ,

examples of what i mean is like search in yahoo messenger list ,,,

Thanks ,

Comment: No offense intended, but you may want to clarify this statement...it's really confusing. - "so i want make simple serch box to search of the list only in the same time and fetch the checkbox which user will search about it using the search box"

Comment: Agreed; I can't really understand this question. Maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like an instant search with jQuery? Here's a tutorial for [that](http://woorkup.com/2010/09/13/how-to-create-your-own-instant-search/).
Otherwise you should really be more specific.

Comment: yes i want thing like this but instead of searching in data base ! , i want it to search in ul list contain checkboxes options